# Ways to update my html/css/js files in running spring app on tomcat

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, spring, tomcat

What are the best practices and is it even possible?
I have read lot of articles/answers from different google links but can't find an answer that would satisfy me.

This is my situation: I have a spring based webapp(hibernate with postgres in backend, angular and jquery in frontend), it's up and running on tomcat 7 or 8. As and admin I would like to be able to modify page layout, for example specify width or display of an element and save this changes, so that they are updated for every user (files would need to have cache option disabled).
It's like if admin modifies given page styles, they are updated on deployed app's styles.css and everyone can see changes.

What are my options?

UPDATE:
I have an idea and I need someone to verify if it's good:

1. I keep css in database (sth like cssSelector as id and styles as string value)
2. I read it into application only if i detect that it was changed.
3. I use jsp, so I create some string with those style and insert them to `<style></style>` tag in the jsp.
4. It's all rendered in server side (jsp does that right?)
5. Users have all changes after refresh (i will handle somehow the browsers cache)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to keep your CSS (js, images, etc as well if you want) outside of your wars.

If you want to build a user interface for admin to edit CSS that is fine. But when admin wants to release the change then generate CSS files. Deploy the change in staging and verify the change and then push to your production deployment.

You can build more sophistication of preview etc. as per your need.